# React router doesn't load page from other component page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router-dom

I am using react with django in backend. When the link is clicked from component page I want the respective page to open. But page doesn't render anything.

This is my **homepage.js** where main react router is defined.

```
 <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path= "/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/communication">
                <Communication />
            </Route>
            {/* <Route path="/forum-create" component={ForumCreate} /> */}
            <Route path="/calendar">
                <EventCalendar />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/information">
                <Informations />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/links">
                <Links />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

I have defined the `Route` in another from which I want to render page.

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect,} from 'react-router-dom'


function Communication() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Forum />
            {/* <Route path="/forum-create" component={ForumCreate} /> */}

        </div>
    )
}


function Forum() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="page-head">Forum</h2>
            <div className="forum">
                <Link to="forum-create">Create Topic</Link>
                <table className="forum-table">
                    <th>
                        <td>Topic</td>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <td>Date</td>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <td>Posted By</td>
                    </th>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test Topic</td>
                        <td>20/05/2021</td>
                        <td>Awesome User</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Test Topic</td>
                        <td>20/05/2021</td>
                        <td>Awesome User</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


function ForumCreate() {
    return (
        <div>
            Create a Topic Forum
            Some Chagnes
        </div>
    )
}

export default Communication
```

I want to render component `ForumCreate()` from communication page only. I have tried putting path in `homepage.js` inside `Route` but still clicking on `Link` doesn't load up the `ForumCreate` function.
I can render this function if its in `homepage.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Communication` component is being rendered the current path is `path="/communication"`, so if you now render additional routes that have a different path prefix (i.e. something other than "/communication") like `path="/forum-create"`, then when you link to that route the `Switch` no longer matches "/communication" and the `Communication` component unmounts, thus unmounting the `<Route path="/forum-create" component={ForumCreate} />` route component.

The solution is to either declare the forum create route out at the root level with the `Switch` so it's ***always*** available to be matched and rendered, or nested as a sub-route of "/communication".

As a root level route.

```
<Router>
  <Navigation />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path= "/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/communication">
      <Communication />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/forum-create" component={ForumCreate} /> // <-- render in root
    <Route path="/calendar">
      <EventCalendar />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/information">
      <Informations />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/links">
      <Links />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Render as a nested route.

```
function Communication() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Forum />
        <Route
          path="/communication/forum-create" // <-- nested route
          component={ForumCreate}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

function Forum() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="page-head">Forum</h2>
      <div className="forum">
        <Link to="/communication/forum-create"> // <-- nested route
          Create Topic
        </Link>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```